# How to write SQL data in XML

Tags: c#, xml, axapta, xmlwriter

I am new to C# programming, what I have to do is to take some data from Dynamics, which I have no problem with, and pass it to a Visual Studio class by a method, all this in order to create a XML with specific structure and fiscal data.

XML structure:

```
<Catalogo Version="1.0" RFC="SIN120706RX7" TotalCtas="98" Mes="07" Ano="2014">
   <Ctas CodAgrup="1" NumCta="100" Desc="CAJA" Nivel="1" Natur="D"/>
   <Ctas CodAgrup="2" NumCta="120" Desc="BANCOS" Nivel="1" Natur="D"/>
   <Ctas CodAgrup="2.1" NumCta="1200001" Desc="BANCOMER CTA 0190864250" SubCtaDe="120" Nivel="2" Natur="D"/>
...
</Catalogo>
```

I have already created the following code for a XML with x data, this code should be in a class since it is going to be a dll:

```
 XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create("periodo.xml");

 xmlWriter.WriteStartDocument();
 xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Catalogo"); ///set once
 xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("Version", "X");
 xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("RFC", "X");
 xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("TotalCtas", "X");
 xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("Mes", "X");
 xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("Ano", "X");


 xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Ctas"); /// vary depending on the mounth.
 xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("CodAgrup", "X");
 xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("NumCta", "X");
 xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("Desc", "X");
 xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("Nivel", "X");
 xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("Natur", "X");
 xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();

 xmlWriter.WriteEndDocument();
 xmlWriter.Close();
```

`Catalogo` element is set just once, but `Ctas element` can vary the number of rows depending on the activity of that month, so do I need a `for`loop in order to insert a variable number of rows?

Does this work to insert the data I got from Dynamics or do I need 2 methods? One for the `Catalogo` element and another one for the `ctas element`? And how can I do that?

**EDIT**

I just made a method to get the string´s from the query:

```
public void Addcuentas(string[] addct)
            {
                int i;
                int j;
                int n = 4;// variable numer of rows 
                string[] addcta = new string[n * 5]; // there is always be 5 columns

                // save data
                for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
                {
                    for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                    {
                        addcta[i * j] = cata[j];
                    }

                }
            }
```

And i try to fill the XML with the code:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
                {
                    for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                    {
                        xmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Ctas");

                        xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("CodAgrup", (addcta[i * j]));
                        xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("NumCta", (addcta[i * (j + 1)]));
                        xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("Desc", (addcta[i * (j + 2)]));
                        xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("Nivel", (addcta[i * (j + 3)]));
                        xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("Natur", (addcta[i * (j + 4)]));
                        xmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
                    }
                }
```

But i dont really know what i am doing wrong since the XML cant be created, dont know if its the method or the way i´m trying to fill the XML, any help and suggestions are welcome.

Comment: It would be good to have data contracts properties within the business object and convert that one as an XML. Send that XML to SQL. In short while I will try to submit an example.

Comment: Have you tried using a loop? It seems you will need to over over your `ctas` elements. What is your question?

Comment: yes i tried, but i dont know how to insert the data from the querys, should be a method that converts the query into an array? or another kind of method?